# Find files > 0 bytes in length that consist only of NUL in Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, debian, fsck

After fsck'ing an ext4 drive that had been running in a QNAP nas without an fsck for about four years, I now have a number of files that seem but be the correct size (typically 8-12mib), but each byte of their contents is null/NUL/00 (i.e. 0 repeated over and over again when seen in a hex editor).

I've checked this with the 'hexedit' tool as well as sampling various lengths of bytes with 'od'

Rather than search amongst 10,000+ NEF and JPEG image files, is there a way I might be able to automate the search these files and write them to a list - so I can restore them from a backup?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your files contain ONLY the NULL string (no new line, `\n`), you can use `grep` and find to locate these files.

The find command will collect all files that are at least 1 byte in size (`-size +1c`) in the current directory and then use grep to check if they contain *only* repetitions of the NULL character:

```
$ find . -type f -size +1c -exec grep -m 1 -ovP "[^\0]" {} \; 
Binary file ./empty_file with spaces.jpg matches
Binary file ./empty_file matches
```

The `-v` flag of grep causes it to print non matching lines. `-m` 1 means "Stop after the first match", `-o` means print only the part of the line that matches (avoids printing empty lines from other files) and `P` uses Perl regular expressions.  The pattern `[^\0]`, means any non `NULL` character. By reversing this (`-v`) and adding the `-m 1` flag, grep will report a match *only* if the file contains nothing but `NULL`.

Finally, you can pipe this through `cut` and `sed` to print the name of the matching file alone:

```
$ find . -type f -size +1c -exec grep -m 1 -ovP "[^\0]" {} \; | cut -d ' ' -f 3- | sed 's/ matches//'
./empty_file with spaces.jpg
./empty_file
```

Comment: I couldn't seem to get the grep options '-ov' to get me the result you describe above, however this worked: 'find . -type f -size +1c -exec grep -m 1 -LP "[^\0]" {} \;' though I'm not sure it's exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answer is much more thorough (and less convoluted) in its inspection of the files, cobbled together the following. There are a few extra commands just to deal with the odd way in which the NAS handles filenames, but it uses 'od' to get the first 32 bytes of the file (my rationale was that if the first 32 bytes are null, then the rest are likely to be too, especially for images):

```
find "$(pwd)" -type f -exec sh -c 'file=$(echo "{}" | sed "s/([\(\)])/\\\1/g"); check=$(od -N32 -w32 -x "$file"); if echo $check | grep --quiet " 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000"; then echo "$file" $check; fi' \;
```

I tried this on a subset of the folders I suspect are corrupted and I saved the results out to a file. After checking each file by hand I was pretty happy that it was reliable.