# Finding files that are mostly NUL

Tags: windows, find, grep

I've got a hard drive copy that went bad where many files are of correct size but are completely filled with `NUL` (`0x00`) bytes.  However, a couple of the files seem to have a couple KB of actual data.

Is there a utility for finding these files in Windows so that I can delete them?  Maybe something that will allow me to sort a list of all files by the percentage of bytes that are NUL?

There seems to be [a way to do this with Grep](https://superuser.com/questions/549064/find-files-0-bytes-in-length-that-consist-only-of-nul-in-debian-ubuntu), but that method appears to only work if the files are completely NUL.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by deleting files with data other NUL characters?  If its your trying to sanitize the hdd you should use tools designed to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound No, this is a copy I made of an old hard drive.  I didn't realize the copy was bad until I got rid of the drive.  I have a bunch of files, but many of them are damaged (filled with, or mostly filled with NUL bytes).  I want to simply delete the damaged files, leaving what is left.

Comment: [Similar question for Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1242510/432690) with few solutions.